# Numeric conversion from string returns undefined, Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, type-conversion, undefined, arrow-functions

Recursive function returns undefined while the log prints the expected value. Could this have something to do with .map() or .reduce()?

```js
console.log(parseInt(digital_root(16)))
//Expected: 7
//Actual: NaN
console.log(digital_root(456))
//Expected: 6
//Actual: undefined

function digital_root(n) {
    if(n < 10){
        console.log(n)
        //digital_root(16) --> 16 (expected)
        //digital_root(456) --> 456 (expected)
        return n
    }else{
        digital_root(String(n).split("").map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `return` on the recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `return` statement in both: `if` and `else` clauses:

```
function digital_root(n) {
    if(n < 10){
        console.log(n)
        //digital_root(16) --> 16 (expected)
        //digital_root(456) --> 456 (expected)
        return n
    }else{
        return digital_root(String(n).split("").map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
    }
}
```